# Taking partial derivative of matrix

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

Let's say that I have an error function, E, such that:
$$ E_p = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{j}(\delta_{pj})^2$$

If I take the partial derivative like this:

$$\frac{\partial{E_p}}{\partial{\delta_{pj}}} $$

will I get:

$$ \frac{\partial{E_p}}{\partial{\delta_{pj}}} = \delta_{pj}$$?

And if I take the partial derivative like this:

$$\frac{\partial{E_p}}{\partial{\delta_{p}}} $$
(notice that I've dropped the subscript, j),

will I get:

$$ \frac{\partial{E_p}}{\partial{\delta_{p}}}  = \sum_{j}(\delta_{pj}) $$
?

I'm trying to understand the effect that taking a partial derivative has on a summation involving a vector (especially when there are different indexes used in the derivatives) because I've had trouble finding information about that subject in particular. Maybe I just don't know what to search for, so if someone has a link to an article that will help me understand this matter, I will greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

$E_p$ is defined via a sum and let me use a dummy variable $k$ for that index of summation.

$$
E_p=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k}(\delta_{pk})^2
$$

Now vix a particular value of $j$ and differentiate.

$$
\frac{\partial E_p}{\partial \delta_{pj}}=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k}2\delta_{pk}\frac{\partial \delta_{pk}}{\partial \delta_{pj}}=
\sum_{k}\delta_{pk}\frac{\partial \delta_{pk}}{\partial \delta_{pj}}
$$

$\delta_{p1},\delta_{p2},\cdots$ are independent so we can write

$$
\frac{\partial \delta_{pk}}{\partial \delta_{pj}}=\Delta_{kj}
$$

I use a nonstandard notation $\Delta_{kj}$ for the delta kronecker symbol. The delta kronecker is equal to $1$ when $k=j$ and $0$ when $k\neq j$, with this we can now sum

$$
\frac{\partial E_p}{\partial \delta_{pj}}=\sum_{k}\delta_{pk}\Delta_{kj}=\delta_{pj}
$$

What messes a lot of people up on questions like this is using the symbol $j$ in two ways: one as a dummy variable in the sum and as a particular value when you differentiate with respect to $\delta_{pj}$, overloading this symbol can cause confusion.

For your second question I am not sure what you mean by $\delta_{p}$. If you mean $\delta_{p}=(\delta_{p1},\delta_{p2},\cdots)$, then your notation reflects a Russian style of taking a gradient.

$$
\frac{\partial E_p}{\partial \delta_p}=\sum_{j}\frac{\partial E_p}{\partial \delta_{pj}}\hat{e}_j
$$

Where $\hat{e}_j$ is a unit vector, oriented in the $\delta_{pj}$ direction. Using the previous result

$$
\frac{\partial E_p}{\partial \delta_p}=\sum_{j}\delta_{pj}\hat{e}_j=\delta_p
$$

but perhaps you have something else in mind for the symbol $\delta_p$ and how to define differentiation with respect to that symbol. Hope that helps.